# UIImageView making other Views inconsistent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, interface-builder, ios-camera

I've designed a `ViewController` with an `ImageView`, 3 `Label-TextField` combination, one single `Label` and one `Toolbar` at the bottom of the view. All of these view elements are inside a `Stack View`. The design is like below:[image: Design from Main storyboard]

The `contentMode` property of the `ImageView` is set to **Aspect Fit** in the Attributes Inspector.

Now when I run the app and select different size of photos, the `ImageView` seems to be inconsistent different times. Like:

> The teal color background the `ImageView` is set to distinguish the difference between the `ImageView` and the original **Background**.

[image: No problem in the view]

This is okay. But when I choose a large size photo it seems to be inconsistent as the `ImageView` is overlapping the `Toolbar` below and this time the `Camera` button is no more clickable. Here is the image:[image: Camera button not clickable]

And the design gets more broken when I choose another photo. The view is showing up differently in different times. Screenshots are:[image: Same image but different behaviour 1] and [image: Same image but different behaviour 2]

> Now what to do? I haven't done any of these design from the code side, all from the **Interface Builder**.
>
> **Any help will be appreciable.**

I have these options in the **Drawing** section of **Attributes Inspector**:[image: Drawing section of Attributes Inspector]

And this is my `Stack View`'s attributes:
[image: Stack View's attributes]

Comment: you have to give fix size and width of your imageview that you set image and make imageview Aspect fill your problem solve.

Comment: Do you want your `UIImageView` to be fixed sized or variable?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan the image should be fit within the `UIImageView` while maintaining the image’s original aspect ratio. Will that need to have fixed sized `UIImageView` ?

Comment: Set `UIImageView` height by either explicit constraint or by `Stack View`'s `Distribution` property so that it's fixed.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya What did you actually mean by _size_ and _width_ ? Do you mean _height_ and _width_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching a lot of ways around, I finally was able to sort out the issue. Setting the **content hugging priority**(don't want to grow) and **content compression resistance priority**(don't want to shrink) helps a lot. Basically I needed to adjust the elements vertically. So tuning the vertical priorities for each element solved my problem. As I have to keep the size of the `ImageView` to be changed from time to time I've made it's vertical **hugging** and **compression** to lower than the other elements of the `Stack View`. Other priorities are kept as they were by default.

To visualise the situation, here is attached images. Color combinations are used here to distinguish among the *elements* of the `Stack View`.[image: Design]
[image: Priorities]

> Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems everything is fine. Just add height constraint in your Toolbar. The problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've checked `Clip To Bounds` property of `UIImageView` in Attributes Inspector.

[image]

Second, set your constraints and / or `Stack View`'s `Distribution` property in such way that all your views fits within available height.

Here's a sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5a7r0oz1v8vclgz/AspectFitImageView.zip?dl=0

Comment: There is no **Clip To Bounds** in my Attributes Inspector. Edited my question with the options of `Drawing` available to me.

Comment: Did you select your `UIImageView`? Please double check or share your Xcode's version.

Comment: Yes. I checked that again selecting `UIImageView`. But nothing :( And my Xcode is **Version 7.2 (7C68)**

Comment: Let me share a sample with you.

Comment: That would be great :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I have to check it at a later time with Xcode 8.1. I'll let you know if that works or not for me :)